# Find if class has border in css

Tags: css, border

Find if class has border in css only, by using attribute selector or by any other means.If it is not having then apply the border.Intention is  Not to fall back on to either jquery. Is this possible to acheive?

---

**Edited** to include response from @nag (OP):

In IE8 there is no `border` for `select`. So I'm trying to do a css reset like this:

```
select, input[type="file"], textarea {
    border: solid 1px #7F9DB9;
 }
```

The problem is it is overriding any preexisiting style because of specificity. I tried to use expression filter but with DocType in IE8 it does not seem to work.

Comment: @ try to do that using !important if default css does not have same sign

Answer (score 1):

CSS has no concept, or implementation, of `if/else` statements, so this is not possible in CSS only.

However, if you define the `border` for an element, and then later redefine that `border` the second statement will override the first (assuming an equally specific selector), so I'm unsure as to *why* you need to apply a `border` only **if** the element doesn't already have a `border` defined:

```
div {
    border: none; /* removes the border */
}

/* other stuff */

div {
    border: 1px solid #f90; /* defines the border */
}
```

Similarly:

```
div {
    border: 5px solid #0f0; /* defines the border */
}

/* other stuff */

div {
    border: 1px solid #f90; /* re-defines the border */
}
```

If you can define your use-case it might be possible to help you further.

---

**Edited** to address the further information in the question:

> In IE8 there is no border for select. So I'm trying to do a css reset like this:

```
select, input[type="file"], textarea {
    border: solid 1px #7F9DB9;
}
```

> The problem is it is overriding any preexisiting style because of specificity. I tried to use expression filter but with DocType in IE8 it does not seem to work.

If the problem is specificity, then the only options you have are to either *increase* the specificity of the selector you want to apply, ideally use an `id`, or multiple `id`s, in your selector (the `id` of an ancestor element is fine) since that's the most specific selector available.

Or, you can *decrease* the specificity of the selector you want to override.

It's worth noting that the `select` element is difficult to style reliably since it's often rendered by the underlying OS, rather than the browser itself, for a consistent look within that operating system.

Answer (score 0):

You have three alternatives:

1. Use JavaScript - that has logic, so you can check whether it has a border or not and then do something with the result. You can use a library like jQuery or MooTools to make it easier.
2. Make this selector more specific, so that it only applies to elements that you want it to.
3. Make your other selectors more specific with classes, IDs, or nested selectors (like `form textarea`).